# Visual Studio keeps changing resx files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resources

I'm working on a VB.Net project and using SVN. I noticed that every time I open my main form, Visual studio slightly modifies my .resx file, which means that I keep having to re-commit it, which is quite annoying.

Has anybody experienced such problems? A diff file demonstrating the problem can be seen at http://synchronicity.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synchronicity/trunk/Create%20Synchronicity/MainForm.resx?r1=272&r2=359&pathrev=359

Thanks,
CFP.

Comment: I've noticed the same problem in Visual Studio 2012. I also noticed that after a couple of months of re-committing the changes, over time the icons get darker, causing me to have to re-import the original images so that they look correct again. I've now stopped committing .resx files that I know I haven't changed, and revert them instead.

Comment: Its now 2020, VS 2019 still does the same. Enough to open a form in a VB.NET project which is under source control, VS will check it out, when saved (for example you change the code behind it but not the layout) its the same logical content in the .resx and .designer.vb files but most lines rearranged. Makes no sense.

Comment: I am noticing this in Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 on .NET 5, WinForms.  Affecting ImageList ImageStream encoding, mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64". Seems to be an ongoing problem and I worry about the visual changes.

Comment: I've reported the issue here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Corruption-of-ImageListImageStream-PNG/1472388

Answer (score -2):

Bit late, but this sounds like a problem I raised with Microsoft around Image Lists:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/428868/png-files-corrupted-in-an-imagelist-when-opening-and-closing-a-form

Comment: That's interesting, but not an answer.  Can you add to this?  Your link ends with an escalation post from Microsoft: has it been acted on?  Is there a solution now and can you link to it?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As @Nadeem_MK predicted the link **has** become invalid. I get "Page not found".

Comment: Apologies, I should have copied the text here! I spent a long time trying to get Microsoft to actually recognise there was a problem, sent them example projects, diffs etc. and they kept closing the issue without any explanation. After much pursuing they finally admitted there was an issue. Their last comment was "Update: We finally found the root cause of this problem, which is inside System.Drawing.dll, but consider it's end in our current release time frame, we would work on the fix in future release." in November 2009.

Comment: In my case the problem was that the png files were being changed whenever you edited a form and so the resx was changing. Microsoft kept insisting the handle was saved and this was the only change and was causing the issue. In fact the png file itself was changing subtly causing the image to actually degrade over time with many saves. That's why I kept pursuing it as it wasn't just causing version control issues it actually made the application look worse over time.